# Align DIV tag without float:left

Tags: css

I have a problem with alignment of image and content in a list. Here is what my code is:

```
 <li> 
   <div class="small-view-image">
       <img src="../images/xyz.png" height="41" width="34" alt="Test" title="Test"/>
   </div>
   <div class="small-view-content">
     <a href='../xyz.html'>XYZ</a>
   </div>                        
 </li>
```

The problem is I cannot use float left to align the image on left and the content on right.  [alt text http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/271/layoutd.png](http://img831.imageshack.us/img831/271/layoutd.png)

This is the output  I am expecting. I cannot use the float:left because, the page is multilingual.  Any suggestions or ideas welcome.

Comment: What does being multilingual have to do with float:left?

Comment: @Fosco when you change direction for RTL languages then you will understand what I mean.

Comment: But usually when you change to RTL you also change a lot of the CSS. So why not also change the floating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on dylanfm's answer with a tweak, your CSS would be:

```
li {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.small-view-image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.small-view-content {
    position: relative;
    left: 40px; /* Makes room for the image */
}
```

This will make sure that you `<li>` properly pushes down other page elements if the text is taller than the image.

Comment: thanks.. but, the problem is when I change direction of the page, the list gets spoiled. I think the only way is to change the CSS and floatings for RTL language.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `li` to have `position: relative` and position the image and text absolutely within it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li>
  <div>img src="../images/xyz.png" height="41" width="34" alt="Test" title="Test"/></div> 
  <a href='../xyz.html'>XYZ</a>
```

Note you can still apply specific style to the two elements above:

```
li > div {display:inline-block; width:?px}
li > a { ... }
```

Edited as per comments.

Comment: The prob with this format is, the text is displayed aligned on the right side, but not vertically aligned!

Comment: I see, that means your images are not all the same width if I understand properly. In such case, putting the image in a <div> makes sense, although no need to put your <a> in a <div>. As you were told by others, set the 'display' property of the <div> used as a container for your image as 'inline-block', in which case you can control its width in pixel using the 'width' property.